# OpenCV Exporting Runnable JAR in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, opencv, jar

While Exporting Runnable JAR in Eclipse, Got error as no open cv in java.library.path.

Included Steps :-

1. Created User Library (ex OpenCV320) in eclipse and added in project build path also dll (as my system is 64 bit "C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\java\x64") opencv_java320.dll is set as Native library Location.
2. While exporting runnable jar selected "Extract required libraries into generated jar".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

1. No need to create separate user library.
2. Add below code.

   String libraryPath = "C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\java\x64";
       System.setProperty("java.library.path", libraryPath);
       Field sysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
       sysPath.setAccessible(true);
       sysPath.set(null, null);

3.And export the runnable jar.